# Insert and updating the data to database from frontend

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, angular, express

I am new to web development. I am working in development of an angular application. I have developed an Angular form in front end, Node.js and Sql server in backend. I need some help to connect my angular form to the sql server database. I want to save the data from my angular form to my sql server database.

Versions:
Angular CLI: 8.0.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.1

I have tried using the restful api to insert data through the server page using post and get.

How can i to connect my angular form to sql databse and insert and update the data when the submit button in my angular form is clicked.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var tediousExpress = require("express4-tedious");
var path = require("path")
var app = express();



// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});



app.get('/', function (req, res) {


    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        server:'******',
        database: '*******',
        user:'******',
        password: '*****',
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.contact', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) 
            console.log(err)

else
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

        });
    });
});

app.use("/contact", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/src/app/contact/contact.component.html");
  });
  app.use("/product", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/src/app/product/product.component.html");
  });
  app.use("/homepage", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/src/app/home/home.component.html");
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}....`));
```

`````
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1 class="well">
      We are available here for you
    </h1>
    <div class="loader" *ngIf="dataloading"></div>

    <div class = "row">
      <div class="column">
          <div class ="container">
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-area"> 
          <form role="form" (ngSubmit)="processForm()">
          <br style="clear:both">
          <h3 style="margin-bottom: 50px; text-align: center;">Contact</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input required ngModel name="Name" #FirstName="ngModel" (change)="log(Name)" type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"  *ngIf="Name.touched && !Name.valid" > Name is required.</div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <input required  type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
          <div class="alert alert-danger"  *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid" > Email is required.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" [(ngModel)]="mobile" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" [(ngModel)]="subject" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message max(200)" [(ngModel)]="message" maxlength="140" rows="7"></textarea>              
          </div>
          <hr class="mb-4">
          <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="save(name, email, mobile, subject, message)">Submit</button>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
````
````contact.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent {
  title = 'Simple Example Contact-us page using Angular 4';
  public data:any=[]


  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }

  save(name, email, mobile, subject, message): void {
    this.data['name']= name;
                this.data['email']= email;
                this.data['mobile']= mobile;
                this.data['subject']= subject;
                this.data['message']= message;
    console.log(this.data);
                //add request to send email or into mysql
                this.http.post<any>('/contact1', this.data).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          console.log("Server-side error occurred.");
        }
      });
   }
}

````
`````

Comment: And your problem/question is...?

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have updated it please check it.

Comment: Collect the data from the form and send it to server according its API. What did you try to do? What error did you get? At the moment your question looks like "please write the code for me".

Comment: I am able to read and insert the data from my server page to the database. i need guidance on how should i connect my angular form to the database(routing my contact.component.html and contact.component.ts(contact form) to server.js(server))

Comment: Why are we mixing Angular2 (*Client side*) within ExpressJS (*Server side*)? Create a couple of applications; one in ExpressJS for interacting with MS SQL Server and other in Angular 2+ that can AJAX to ExpressJS Web API to CRUD Operations.

Comment: @kris Angular has nice "getting started" guide, please spend 15 minutes on reading it and I'm sure most of your questions will disappear or at least you will be able to formulate what exactly does not work... https://angular.io/start